# Importing data frames from another python script

Tags: python, pandas

I have one script full of data frames :

```
#df.py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
.
.
dfn = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
```

Also I have a function in this script that concatenates all dfs starting with a prefix:

```
def conc_all(prefix='df'):
    dfs = [df for name, df in globals().items() if name.startswith(prefix)
           and isinstance(df, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame))]
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis =1)
```

Within my second script, I wish to import from the df script the concatenated dfs:

```
#second.py
from df import *
all_dfs = conc_all()
```

But it leads to: `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

If I go to `dfs.py`, create the `dfs` and concatenate them with `conc_all()`, it works perfectly. So, the issue must be in the import.

My goal here is to create all the dfs in `df.py`, concatenated them and import the concatenated df to `second.py`, in an effort to keep `second.py` shorter and cleaner.

Comment: `from df import *`, not `dy.py`.

Comment: @hcheung I apologize. Actually my code is `from df import *`. I edited the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Me either, are the `conc_all()` in the same file of `df.py`? where is the `dfs.py` you mentioned?

Comment: @hcheung, yes `conc_all` is in the same `df.py`. Both `df.py` and `second.py` are in the same folder. My impression is that the issue has something to do with the global/local thing but I can not figure it out. It seems that since the dfs are created in `df.py` but I am trying to run `conc_all` from `second.py`, it can not find the dfs defined in `df.py` thus it says no objects found to be concatenated.